# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Directory 'uploads/' for the site filebrowser.filebrowser does not exist.

Tags: python

I am trying to use FileBrowseFile in my project but when i run the program it says django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Directory 'uploads/' for the site filebrowser.filebrowser does not exist.

my settings file looks like

```
MEDIA_ROOT = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT", settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
MEDIA_URL = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_URL", settings.MEDIA_URL)
DIRECTORY = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY", 'uploads/')
```

my models.py has

```
banner_url = FileBrowseField("Image",max_length=200,blank=True,null=True, extensions=['.jpg'])
```

what can be done to get rid of this error?

Comment: I would have to say, the directory `uploads/` must not exist. Are you sure you have put it in the right place?

Comment: what you mean by right place?

Comment: The "right place" would depend on your environment. First, make sure your `MEDIA_ROOT` is an absolute path. I'm fairly certain that it will be looking for `uploads/` within `MEDIA_ROOT`. If that doesn't work, try using an absolute path to `uploads/` as well.